# Is two-step query with shortestPath() the most efficient solution to find shortest paths from one node to multiple nodes?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I'm still learning the ropes of Neo4j and trying to decide if it is the right tool for the problem I need to solve. My goal is to calculate distance from one node to every single node in a certain group of nodes. So far, I'm trying something like this:

```
START n = node:node_auto_index(name="Animals") 
MATCH ppl:person 
WITH n, ppl 
MATCH p = shortestPath(n-[*]-ppl) 
RETURN length(p), ppl
```

(I'm doing it on a 'friends of friends' [sample dataset](http://www.neo4j.org/learn/try), having first tagged all people with `:person`.)

The question is: will this query be completed in one traversal, or will Neo4j have to iterate through all nodes in `ppl`, increasing the computational costs linearly with the number of nodes in `ppl`? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: What does ppl:person means??

Comment: In Neo4j 2.0, that's a way of telling it to match against a label. So this is saying that the ppl nodes should have a label of person.

Answer (score 0):

What you are requesting is to calculate the shortest Paths from n to all Nodes with the Label `:person`. Of course this does only scale linearly as the amount of your people nodes grows, you will also get increasing amounts of shortest paths.